# Is it possible to integrate a python function in a R script?

Tags: python, r

I've defined a python function and I want to integrate it in R, is it possible?

This is the python code I want to integrate:

```py
def set_priority_py(overlap,Priority,IEC_category):
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import math as m

    #priority = (3,2,1,4,5,6,7)
    #category = ("a","b","c","d","e","f","g")
    #overlap = (float('NaN'),1,1,1,0,1,1)
    priority = Priority
    category = IEC_category
    #overlap = overlap

    data = pd.DataFrame({'priority':priority,'category':category,'overlap':overlap})

    data['new'] = np.nan
    data['new2'] = np.nan
    #rest = []
    data['rest'] = ""
    for i in range(1, len(data)):
        if data.overlap.loc[i] == True:
            if data.priority.loc[i]<= (data.priority.loc[i-1] if m.isnan(data.new.loc[i-1]) else data.new.loc[i-1]):
                data.new.loc[i] = data.priority.loc[i]
                data.new2.loc[i] = data.category.loc[i]
                #rest.append(data.category[i-1])
                #data.rest[i] = rest
                data.rest.loc[i] = ''.join([str(data.rest.loc[i-1]),',',str(data.category.loc[i-1])])
            else:
                data.new.loc[i] = data.priority.loc[i-1]
                data.new2.loc[i] = data.category.loc[i-1]
                #rest.append(data.category[i])
                #data.rest[i] = rest
                data.rest.loc[i] = ''.join([str(data.rest.loc[i-1]),',',str(data.category.loc[i])])
    data.rest = data.rest.str[1:]
    return data
```

The result with a random dataframe is:

```
priority    category    overlap new new2    rest
0   3   a   NaN NaN NaN 
1   2   b   1.0 2.0 b   a
2   1   c   1.0 1.0 c   a,b
3   4   d   1.0 1.0 c   a,b,d
4   5   e   0.0 NaN NaN 
5   6   f   1.0 5.0 e   f
6   7   g   1.0 6.0 f   f,g
```

Is is possible to create a function that works in R? I've tried to integrate it with "reticulate" package, but my program crashes.

This is the code, when I execute the 2nd line RStudio crashes.

```r
  source_python("set_priority_py.py")
  set_priority(overlap,Priority,IEC_category)
```

**EDIT**

The code is working for 20 random samples created in this example:

```r
  overlap <- as.logical(sample(c(0,1),size=20, replace = TRUE))
  Priority<- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7),size=20, replace = TRUE)
  IEC_category<-sample(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"),size=20, replace = TRUE)
  source_python("set_priority_py.py")
  set_priority(overlap,Priority,IEC_category)
```

Comment: Perhaps check out reticulate: https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/

Comment: See the reticulate package. Or you can just run python using `system` or such and get the results back to R

Comment: I was just about to write the same: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3340120/how-to-run-python-in-r.html

Comment: Where have you defined a function? Functions are created with the `def` keyword.

Comment: @gersht, yes I have. Now the post is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R's `reticulate` package should be the solution to your problem.

You can create a python script file, calling it for example `useful_function.py` and have in it

```py
def useful_function(x):
    return x *2
```

Then in R you can simply load the function to your workspace

```
library(reticulate)
use_python("/path/to/your/python/interpreter")

# source the created python script
source_python("useful_function.py")

result <- useful_function(2)
print(result)
```

If you're having additional troubles with reticulate and your code you can post here the error message so we can help you out better.

Comment: Your example is exactly what I've done. I don't have error message, the program crashes.

Comment: Does your program crash if you run it in a Python interpreter ? Does it give a error message then?

Comment: > source_python("set_priority_py.py")
Warning messages:
1: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="C:\PROGRA~3\ANACON~1\envs\rstudio/python.exe": The system cannot find the file specified
2: In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="C:\PROGRA~3\ANACON~1\envs\rstudio-1.1.456/python.exe": The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: It seems R's having trouble finding your python interpreter, can you try explicitly telling it where it is? Use `use_python("/path/to/your/python/interpreter")`. I edited my original answer so you get a sense of what it should be like.

Comment: where are you saving the `.py` script though?

Comment: It can be wherever you want as long as you correctly point the path to it in `source_python`. In this case I had it in the same directory as my R script